# Flattery vs Being Nice

Tags: halacha, middos-character-traits

**Flattery is [forbidden](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/practical-halacha/chanifa-flattery-halacha/)**

[talmud:](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.41b.11)

> Rabbi Elazar says: Any person who has flattery in him brings wrath to the world, as it is stated: “But those with flattery in their hearts bring about wrath” (Job 36:13). And moreover, his prayer is not heard, as it is stated in that same verse: “They do not cry for help when He binds them.”

There are **exceptions** for example your wife for peace, you teacher to teach you and for peace (to protect yourself)
[Pele Yoetz](http://www.peleyoetz.com/PeleYoetz.aspx?ID=121)

> flattery our Sages allowed towards a person’s wife, for the sake of domestic peace, and towards his rabbi, so that he should teach him Torah. A person is also allowed to flatter wicked people due to the ways of peace.

**but it is good to be nice** (to say what people what to hear, even when it is not "true") **always** and **to all** peaple/creations
[talmud](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.17a.1):

> Beit Shammai said to Beit Hillel: In a case where the bride was lame or blind, does one say with regard to her: A fair and attractive bride? But the Torah states: “Keep you from a false matter” (Exodus 23:7). Beit Hillel said to Beit Shammai: According to your statement, with regard to one who acquired an inferior acquisition from the market, should another praise it and enhance its value in his eyes or condemn it and diminish its value in his eyes? You must say that he should praise it and enhance its value in his eyes and refrain from causing him anguish. From here the Sages said: A person’s disposition should always be empathetic with mankind, and treat everyone courteously. In this case too, once the groom has married his bride, one praises her as being fair and attractive.

[rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Ketubot.17a.1.4/)

> לעשות לאיש ואיש כרצונו

[rambam](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=1&hilchos=1&perek=5&halocha=11)

> הָיָה דִּבּוּרוֹ בְּנַחַת עִם הַבְּרִיּוֹת **וְדַעְתּוֹ מְעֹרֶבֶת עִמָּהֶם**
>   his social conduct is [attractive] to others

**what is the difference? (when is it being nice when is it flattery?)**
sources please

Comment: read this https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%AA

Comment: ויחניף אדם לאשתו, משום שלום בית. וכן לבעל חובו, שלא ילחצנו. לרבו, שילמדנו תורה. ומצווה גדולה להחניף לתלמידיו ולחבריו, כדי שילמדו ושישמעו לדבריו, לקבל תוכחתו לקיים המצוות. וכן כל אדם שהוא סבור שימשכנו אליו, שישמע לו לקיים המצוות, ואם יבוא עליו בכעס לא ישמע לו אלא בחניפות יקבל תוכחתו – מצווה גדולה להחניף לו כדי להוציא יקר מזולל. כי יש אדם שאינו מקבל תוכחה בגערה אלא בנחת, שנאמר (קהלת ט יז): "דברי חכמים בנחת נשמעים".

Comment: @kouty yes I see very nice but latter he says לכן צריך הצדיק להתרחק מאוד מן החניפות, שלא יחניף ולא יקבל החניפות מאחרים. So it is not clear to me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57358/discussion-between-kouty-and-hazoriz).

Comment: _hanifa_ in Jewish literature generally refers to flattering others for the purpose of personal gain. This is very different from validating others, or otherwise making them feel good for the purpose of helping them.

Comment: See the context in e.g.  תוספתא מסכת סוטה (מהד' הגר"ש ליברמן) פרק ז 
ר' נתן אמרו נתחייבו ישראל כלייה שחינפו לאגריפס המלך , ספר חובות הלבבות שער ג - שער עבודת האלוקים פרק ג 
שתהיה כונתו לחנופה ולשבח בני אדם וכבודם בעבורה, כי שרשה מיוסד על התוחלת והרהות, אך העבודה שהיא מצד הערת השכל לא תהיה כי אם מיוחדת לשם שמים, לא יתערב בה שום חונף ולא זיוף מצד שיתפאר בה.

Comment: @mevaqesh it seems I was wrong, I do not see how your source prove your point, the way I understand them is:  the first one is the regarding the Jews flattering a bad deed of the king (I do not know what they gained for the flattery it seems they  were just showing there love), the second one is that someone serves Hashem for the flattery and praise he will receive, (but not whole hartedly), nothing regarding a prohibition of flattery or gaining something from it

Comment: It is pretty obvious that the point of praising a king is for self-benefit. I never said there was a prohibition of flattery; you did! (In reality like most bad middot it isn't forbidden by the Torah, or banned by some formal prohibition, it is just bad behaviour which is what the Hovot HaLevavot is discussing): At least if the translation is to be relied on, _hanifa_ refers to trying to accrue some benefit from others. Like I said, that is usually the context I have seen it used in...

Comment: @mevaqesh thank you for clarifying, so according to your understanding חמשה which the Gemoro recommends not to do is when you do it to gain, but דעתו של אדם מעורבת עם הבריות which the Gemoro recommends to do is when you do it without a gain

Comment: Exactly. Alternatively it would be about praising sinful behaviour, thus perverting proper values. (This is the understanding of the Yereim you cite in your first link). Either way, the problem isn't the praise itself.

Comment: One aspect of flattery, as I understand it, is often people flatter others as a from of sarcasm. The flatterer gains nothing by it other than revenge or some type of self-satisfaction of saying something to another when he doesn't mean it. It's a false way of being nice to someone. Saying something nice to someone when the attribute is false, has the opposite intention. The person wants good for the receiver, and at the same time, he wants to avoid embarrassing the other one or hurting their feelings by mentioning a flaw. So, compliment your wife when she gives you burnt food!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from [an article about the prohibition of flattery](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?cat=361&id=21963&q=):

> Although the word chanufah in Modern Hebrew means "flattery," and, indeed, is even occasionally used by Chazal in this sense, the prohibition against chanufah has a slightly different meaning. Chanufah is the deception that occurs when someone encourages the performance of misdeeds, aveiros, or when someone fraudulently misrepresents something as Torah or as acceptable behavior when it is not.
>   The primary case of chanufah is when someone sees or knows that a person sinned and tells the sinner that he did nothing wrong or, worse still, tells the sinner that the sinful act was the correct thing to do.

In other words, the forbidden flattery you are inquiring about is limited to cases which can cause misunderstanding of the Torah or justify bad behavior. Otherwise, there's no prohibition in being nice to people.

[The article](http://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/shiur.asp?cat=361&id=21963&q=) goes on to delineate different forms of flattery and other aspects and applications of the prohibition; I think you will find the sources mentioned there helpful.

Comment: +1 is it correct to say that to be nice to people is a good thing to do and that there are no boundaries you can lye and be nice for any reason to everyone, **except** complimenting a bad behavior?

Comment: Thank you for defining flattery, but I am also interested in the definition of being nice

Comment: @hazoriz I think there are two distinct issues: 1) the parameters of "chanufah", and 2) the parameters of forbidden lying. Your question was about the former. Your comment  "...there are no boundaries you can lie and be nice for any reason to everyone...", however, introduces a new issue -  the latter issue of honesty. This is really a different question - is it permitted to lie to make someone feel good, does that fall under the Talmudic statement "it is permissible to lie for the sake of sholom" or not. But that would be a question of lying vs being nice, not halachic flattery.

Comment: http://halacha.co/en/flattery/

Comment: @hazoriz Strange. The very source he brings - Shaarei Teshuvah - is in agreement with my answer above that chanufah only applies in special cases (a rasha or when some harm will befall people as a result), but not to regular flattery - though the article implies the opposite. He also quotes from the chapter on lying but applies it instead to flattery (see footnote 10). I don't have time now to look up  his other sources to see if they're also similarly mischaracterized, but if you find any authoritative sources that are actually in conflict with my answer, please let me know.

Comment: @hazoriz hmm....actually to be honest I see that the Pele Yoetz you cite in the question does seem to put regular flattery in the category of chanufah, which would be in conflict. So it seems there is some disagreement about this, though I don't think pele yoetz, which is a relatively recent mussar sefer, is considered halachically on par with the other sources cited in the article.